# SQL Case with no null

Tags: sql, null, case

When I run this query:

```
select
    '1992' = CASE WHEN Year(HireDate) = 1992 THEN count(*) END,
    '1993' = CASE WHEN Year(HireDate) = 1993 THEN count(*) END,
    '1994' = CASE WHEN Year(HireDate) = 1994 THEN count(*) END
  from employees
 group by Year(HireDate)
```

I get:

```
1992     1993      1994
3        NULL      NULL
NULL      3        NULL
NULL     NULL       3
```

How can I change the query to get:

```
1992    1993    1994
3           3      3
```

Answer (score 3):

With this query you will get only a row:

```
select 
'1992'=
count( CASE WHEN Year(HireDate) = 1992 THEN 1 END ),
'1993' =
count( CASE WHEN Year(HireDate) = 1993 THEN 1 END ),
'1994' = 
count( CASE WHEN Year(HireDate) = 1994 THEN 1 END )
from employees
```

Comment: @user1508682: If this answer has actually helped you out, please consider [accepting it formally](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work "How does accepting an answer work?") next time you are here.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
  '1992' = sum (case when year(HireDate) = 1992 THEN 1 else 0 END),
  '1993' = sum (case when year(HireDate) = 1993 THEN 1 else 0 END),
  '1994' = sum (case when year(HireDate) = 1994 THEN 1 else 0 END),
from employees
```